# I am getting a list index out of range when trying to create a langchain agent

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a simple langchain agent, but I'm having a very frustrating time with it.  The documentation isn't very helpful and googling hasn't turned up veru much that's useful.

Here's the source code

```
import os
# unit_test_agent.py
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain_core.prompt_values import PromptValue,StringPromptValue



class UnitTestAnalysisAgent:
    def __init__(self, openai_api_key = None):

        if openai_api_key == None:
            self.openai_api_key = os.environ.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')
        self.llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=self.openai_api_key)

        system_prompt = """
You are a unit test analysis assistant. Your role is to analyze provided unit test results and provide insights, suggestions, and feedback on t
he quality of the code and tests. Be thorough and provide detailed analysis and recommendations.
"""
        prompt = PromptTemplate(
            template=system_prompt + "\n\nInput: {input}",
            input_variables=["input"]
        )
        self.agent = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
            agent=self.llm,
            tools=[],
            memory=ConversationBufferMemory(),
            agent_prompt=prompt,
            input_keys=["input"]
        )    )

    def run(self, unit_test_results):
        # Prepare the input for the agent
        unit_test_analysis_prompt = "Analyze the following unit test results:\n\n" + unit_test_results
        prompt_value = StringPromptValue(text = unit_test_analysis_prompt)


        # Call the agent and get the analysis
        unit_test_analysis = self.agent.invoke(prompt_value)

        return unit_test_analysis
```

The relevant error message I get from langchain is:

```
File "/src/repos/aiops_demo/src/app/agents/unit_test_agent.py", line 40, in run
    unit_test_analysis = self.agent.invoke(prompt_value)
  File "/src/repos/aiops_demo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 133, in invoke
    inputs = self.prep_inputs(input)
  File "/src/repos/aiops_demo/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 479, in prep_inputs
    inputs = {list(_input_keys)[0]: inputs}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've also been looking at the source code for langchain but I'm not getting very far.
I'm really stuck here and don't know how to proceed in fixing this.  I've looked at the langchain API docs but they aren't very helpful.  Can anyone reommend a better source of information for building langchain apps?  I'm running this on an Ubuntu 20.04 server with langchain version 0.1.12

Any help appreciated.